CGW error - 429: Monthly usage exceeds your subscription plan limits
I'm getting this error when trying to sign "CGW error - 429: Monthly usage exceeds your subscription plan limits".
I was hoping changing the RPC url would work, but I still get the error.
Any way around it?

The error went away when I un-clicked "Sponsored by Safe".
I'd been doing extensive testing and was being rate-limited by Gelato.
